# iterate an array with ssh

Tags: arrays, bash, ssh

I am trying to open an ssh shell then run through an array to get status on a list of expected running processes.

Here's what I have:

```
procList=("sdb*" 'fepkrn' 'fepcmd' 'fepmts' 'fepxml' 'fepdbs' 'feprdc' 'feproot' 'fephist2' 'fepagent' 'feprpl gwnma' 'feprpl gwsun' 'feprpl gwper' 'feprpl gwlur')

ssh $1 "for(( p = 0 ; p < ${#procList[@]} ; p++ )); do echo ${procListNOC[$p]}; done"
```

I don't understand why I can't itterate through the array.  The output that I currently get:

```
sdb*
sdb*
sdb*
sdb*
sdb*
sdb*
sdb*
sdb*
sdb*
sdb*
sdb*
sdb*
sdb*
sdb*
```

So, I know that my for loop is working however I also need the echo (to be replaced with a pgrep command) to run through the entire array.

Answer (score 5):

Maybe this:

```
ssh localhost "for p in ${procList[@]}; do echo \$p ; done"
```

that is, you need to expand the array before sending it to the remote host since it is not defined there. In your case you are just expanding `echo ${procListNOC[$p]};` before sending and it expands to `sdb*`. You can see the command you are sending like this:

```
echo "for(( p = 0 ; p < ${#procList[@]} ; p++ )); do echo ${procListNOC[$p]}; done"
```

and that will show you:

```
for(( p = 0 ; p < 14 ; p++ )); do echo sdb*; done
```

If you really need to iterate with an index:

```
ssh localhost "IFS=' ' read -a procList <<< \"${procList[@]}\";\
    for(( p = 0 ; p < \${#procList[@]} ; p++ )); \
    do echo \${procList[\$p]}; done"
```

**Update**

If you create a script like this [`remote.sh`]:

```
#!/bin/bash
procList=("sdb*" 'fepkrn' 'fepcmd' 'fepmts' 'fepxml' 'fepdbs' 
  'feprdc' 'feproot' 'fephist2' 'fepagent' 'feprpl gwnma' 
  'feprpl gwsun' 'feprpl gwper' 'feprpl gwlur')

for p in ${procList[@]}; do
    pgrep $p
done
```

you can do:

```
scp remote.sh remotehost:~/
ssh remotehost sh remote.sh
```

If the script is large you might consider using rsync to reduce the transfer size.

Comment: Thanks.  However the "$P" in this case is the index of arry procList.  So, the ehoc is giving me 1-14.  Would you recommend declaring the array as part of the ssh string?  I'm really confused here because it does itterate through the index...

Comment: do you really need the index? you can do it the way I did it in the first example.

Comment: when you pass the array as a string to the remote host, your `#` will not work.

Comment: Thanks for the help.  I don't need the index however the list of processes that I look for change from time to time.  I do need to pass the arror and get the results back from the pgrep (whcih is sent to /dev/null where I pull the "0" or "non-0" response to determine if the process is running.  The real goal here is that I need this script to run faster; I have to run this on servers across the globe from a central operations center.  I have a version that works but as we expand this portion of the script is getting slower and slower.  Any help is greatly appreciate.

Comment: do you think having an index will speed up the script? Is it slow because the array is very large?

Comment: If you really need to speed this up, store the tokens in a file, not in an array. Then use `rsync` to transfer these tokens.

Comment: I believe it's slow becuase the ssh is opened and closed for each element in the array.  The array ins't large...only ~ 14 values.  AH...I like this.  So, you're saying that I could put the process' that I need to look at in a file then execut the file using the ssh session.  Do you know if I can get status back using that method.  If so, that's clearly the better way of doing this...Thanks!

Comment: updated the answer, here I sent the script that creates an array but you can also send the process patterns as a file only.

Comment: @perreal Thanks, IFS=' ' read -a procList <<< \"${procList[@]}\";\ was exactly what I needed to get an array to the remote machine.

Answer (score 1):

The second argument to ssh is in double quotes (`""`) so it is parameter-expanded *before* being passed to `ssh`. What `ssh` sees (and executes on the remote machine) is:

```
ssh <some hostname> "for(( p = 0 ; p < 14 ; p++ )); do echo sdb*; done"
```

So that's what you see: 14 echos of `sdb*`.